# Can I throw an anonymous object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Mozilla [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw#throw_an_object) that we can define an object and throw it.

This way, we can encapsulate more than a simple string message and send it to the exception consumer (the `catch` block, or the `then` method of promises).

However, I don't want to constantly define types in my JS code.

Is it possible to throw anonymous objects?

I tried `throw new Error({ firstKey: firstValue, secondKey: secondValue })` and it does not work. I get `[object Object]`.

Comment: That works fine, it just means that somewhere in your code, you're turning it into a string instead of looking at the object properties.

Comment: Your object needs a `toString` function for your example to work. Like `throw new Error({firstKey: 1, secondKey: 2, toString: () => 123})`.

Comment: try `throw  { firstKey: firstValue, secondKey: secondValue }` directly

Comment: @R4ncid An Error object is usually a bit nicer to work with: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-throw-literal

Comment: @CertainPerformance, simply open a browser window, open the dev tools, then write `throw new Error({name: 'somebody, age: 40})`. You see `[object Object]` and nowhere you have turned it into string.

Comment: @Lain, I added that `toString` method and now I recieve the return value of that method. That's not what I want. I want to get the object.

Comment: You can derive from Error to make the properties you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, you can throw literally anything:

```js
try {
  throw "a string";
} catch (error) {
  console.log("caught", error)
}

try {
  throw 10;
} catch (error) {
  console.log("caught", error)
}

try {
  throw {a: 1, b: 2};
} catch (error) {
  console.log("caught", error)
}
```

So to answer the question `Is it possible to throw anonymous objects?`: yes it's possible to throw an anonymous object.

Whether you should do so is another question.

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you so much. No complexity. Jus throw an object. And it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Bigboy Glad to be of help. No problem!

Answer (score 2):

When an Error is created, the first parameter passed (if any) is converted to a string, and not used anywhere else. So, just by using the first parameter, there's no way to pass an object along (without using `JSON.stringify`, which would be ugly and also lose information).

But Errors can accept a second argument - [an object with a `cause` property](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-error-message), which will then get put on the error object. You can use this to communicate any information you want, including objects.

```js
const objForCause = {};
try {
  throw new Error(
    'Something went wrong',
    { cause: { prop: 'val', obj: objForCause } }
  );
} catch(err) {
  // Not all errors have causes
  // Ensure that it does before examining further
  if (err.cause) {
    console.log(err.cause);
    console.log(err.cause.obj === objForCause);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read your own question statement carefully. This is what is being said.

1. Define your own object

```
  const myobj={a:1,b:2};
```

2. Then throw it.

```
  throw myobj;
```

3. Use the object however you want

```
console.log(err);
```

Below is a working example.

```js
try {
  const myobj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  };
  throw myobj;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

You can do all sorts of things depending upon your imagination I guess. even attaching a error object instance if you want.